# lights are not showing in blender render mode

Tags: lighting

hey I just started a couple days ago with blender and I don't know why in rendered mode lights are not showing? scene lights and scene world are on. thank you

Comment: Hello, make sure that the *Scene lights* option is enabled in the *Viewport Shading* panel (down arrow on the right of the *Rendered* preview icon on the top right of your 3D view

Comment: hey thanks a lot I figured it out just had to put the area lights the other way around:)